# Assign the latitude and longitude from Geolocation's getCurrentPosition to variables

Tags: javascript, w3c-geolocation

I am trying to use the values of longitude and latitude that are returned by getCurrentPosition() api as shown in the example on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) below:

```html
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

The example above just displays those values on the web page. However, I would like to save them in a local javascript variable (say y and z) so I can use them elsewhere.
For example, if my longitude (`y`) is 10 and latitude (`z`) is 15, then I would be able to display them as follows:

```
y=10
z=15
```

Comment: you might wanna continue with some more basic tutorials before doing geo location stuff

Comment: *...to set the longitude and latitude of this function* I did not quite understand this sentence. Will you explain please?

Comment: the function/script/javascript outputs your longitude and latitude. I would like to set that output to a variable. Then display that variable.

Comment: You probably want to read about ["How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @user7886229, since you accepted an answer, you should consider up voting it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Coords will load momentarily.</p>



<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

var lat = '';
var lon = '';

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    x.innerHTML = lat + " " + lon;


}

getLocation();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You don't have to declare the values at the global level like I did, but thought it might be useful so you can access it outside of the function.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I have a couple more question. 
-What is x.innerHTML?
-How would I make it click automatically (like once the page is loaded)

Comment: x = the "demo" <p tag.  inner html is the contents.  So if you put this on the page: <p id="demo"></p> x.innerHTML = "", but if you put <p id="demo">123</p> it is 123.  If this helps, would appreciate you marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: Also -- updated so that it runs automatically.  You'd probably want to use something like jQuery though so you can use $(document).ready().

Comment: You can use the script I posted above for now, but if you want to do dom changes after page load, go to www.jquery.com and do their tutorial.

Comment: Ok. Will do! But is there anychance there is a way to do it in just javascript or no?

Comment: Yep -- but it's much better in jquery.  Here's a good answer on that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "y= " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>z= " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please consider adding a comment to explain your answer, so others can also learn from it. :)